# SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE structure

Tags: c, sdl

The code I'm trying to compile uses a structure called SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE
I cannot find this structure in the SDL API and the compiler gives me an undeclared(first use in this function) error report.

Is it most likely that the developer wrote false code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naming conventions

First of all `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE` is not a structure, but an enumeration value. Enumerations in `SDL` are all caps while structs while structs and functions are given on the form `SDL` + name starting with uppercase i.e `SDL_Surface`

### SDL_WindowEventID

I have looked through the documentation, and I haven't found any references to `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE`. But there is an enum called `[SDL_WindowEventID][1]` which has values like `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED`

### SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE

After a quick search, I found [this](https://github.com/new299/hackterm/blob/master/libsdl/include/SDL_video.h) chunk of code in a [Github repository](https://github.com/new299/hackterm) :

```
typedef enum
{
    SDL_WINDOWEVENT_NONE,           /**< Never used */

    // ....
    // Lots of enum values
    // ....

    SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE          /**< New event type for rotation of iOS */
} SDL_WindowEventID;
```

After looking [at the blame](https://github.com/new299/hackterm/blame/master/libsdl/include/SDL_video.h#) for this particular file, I found the commit that added this line.

> 53b2576b » new299  2013-04-06 fixed local resize issue

So, without more info, I assume the creator of this project has edited the `SDL_video.h` file and you are either trying to compile this project or a project that builds on it. I

Comment: Okay thanks for the enumeration value bit. And yes this is the project, I'll look at the SDL_video.h file

Comment: @poon Since you're trying to use this particular project, I suggest posting an issue about it and trying to acquire building instructions.

Answer (score 1):

SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ROTATE is a type of event, that is in a enumeration.
The structure you want is SDL_WindowEvent.
It contains the type, timestamp and two integer that are data1 and data2, their content depends on the Window Event Type

For more info, visit : http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent

Btw, which version of SDL are you using ? I pretend you are using SDL-2.0